# How to update Teradata driver in Talend Big Data 7.0

Tags: teradata, talend

I am using Talend Big Data 7.0.1 , while connecting to teradata using teradataInput it is always selecting teradata driver 15.0.1.
How can i change teradata driver from 15.0.1 to 17.0.1 ?

Comment: Far from an expert on Talend, but isn't the driver specified in the database connection?

Comment: Import the new .jar file using the "Modules" view?

Comment: Importing jars in "modules" did not work for me . But I removed the old jars from .m2 repository and created a new job. When I add new teradataInput it gave me an option to download missing jars. After downloading and restart, it worked